# Paypal - woocommerce - sandbox working by intermitence

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

we have a strange problem here on our paypal payment gateway on woocommerce.

The paypal stopped working and all orders gets cancelled. We upgraded everything (woocommerce, plugins, etc). Nothing worked as before.

So we tryed to debug via the sandbox. And here there is a strange behaviour. When we make an order and click on checkout with paypal, the first time we have a error 500 from the paypal server. Then if we click on back from the browser and try again it works perfectly.

Anyone has already faced this issue ?

Thank you for your help,

RF

Comment: Hello @PP_Punna,

Thank you for your answer.

We have tested the solution that you proposed ("Cookies and cache...") but it doesn't change.

On the sandbox we have the same problem and in the live paypal the order are still cancelled.

Can you please help ?

RF

Answer (score 0):

Cookies and cache from the browser, then it works.

Comment: Hello @PP_Punna, Thank you for your answer. We have tested the solution that you proposed ("Cookies and cache...") but it doesn't change. On the sandbox we have the same problem and in the live paypal the order are still cancelled. Can you please help ? RF

Comment: Can you please share the PayPal API response logs for checking further.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer. Here is the Paypal API log.
You will see that some works and some don't :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/21mk4zjexppmh14/AADiPdd8SyuRY4__7zZIaY2Aa?dl=0
Thank you again,
Renato